# pypandoc | Convert multiple files

Tags: python, pypandoc

**Objective:**

I want to use `Pypandoc` to create a function where the user inputs three arguments being:
(i) an input folder;
(ii) a file format to convert to; and
(iii) an output folder.

**Problem:**

Before I convert this to a loop to convert multiple files, I want to get it working with one file. The code runs from the following directory:

```
*C:\workspace\code\doc_check\venv\Scripts\*
```

The directory containing the files to convert is:

```
*C:\workspace\code\doc_check\test_folder*
```

The directory I want to output to is:

```
*C:\workspace\code\doc_check\output*
```

Here is my code, followed by the error message I keep receiving:

```
import pypandoc
import os

# Convert Word document to .md using pypandoc.

def convert(input_dir, output_format, output_dir):
    data_files = os.listdir(input_dir)
    path_name = os.path.join(input_dir, data_files[0])
    output = pypandoc.convert_file(path_name, output_format, outputfile=output_dir + 'test_doc.md')
    return output

convert('test_folder', 'md', 'output')
```

**Error message:**

```
C:\workspace\code\doc_check\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/workspace/code/doc_check/venv/Scripts/doc_check.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/workspace/code/doc_check/venv/Scripts/doc_check.py", line 18, in <module>
    convert('test_folder', 'md', 'output')
  File "C:/workspace/code/doc_check/venv/Scripts/doc_check.py", line 7, in convert
    data_files = os.listdir(input_dir)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'test_folder'
```

Comment: The system is looking for a directory inside the current working directory, which you say is `Scripts`. Since neither of those directories are in the CWD, you need to provide the path like `../../test_folder`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  How do I specify and output directory and get the output file to take the name of the file it converted? At the moment it's outputting to `C:\workspace\code\doc_check` and naming the converted file `outputtest_doc.md`.

Comment: Well, you're specifying the file name with `outputfile=output_dir + 'test_doc.md'`. If you want a different file name, you need to specify something other than `test_doc.md`.